# how to do 'order by' in python eval() statement?

Tags: python, pandas, eval

In my Python code, I have a query, I want to select the rows from a DataFrame where ID is specified and HOUR <= specified, but I want to select only 6 of them. So I want to order the selection to avoid of selecting too many. I got error.

```
ID='IDTET'

t=some timestamp

HistoryThreshold=5

selection=df[df.eval("MY_ID=='%s' and HOUR<='%s' and valid=='%s' ORDER BY HOUR DESC LIMIT '%s'" %(ID,t,'yes',HistoryThreshold+1))]
```

I got error:

> ```
>   MY_ID =='IDTET'and HOUR <='2019-06-18 08:00:00'and valid =='yes'ORDER BY HOUR DESC LIMIT '6'
>     SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

If I only do this part part, there is no error:

```
selection=df[df.eval("MY_ID=='%s' and HOUR<='%s' and valid=='%s'"%(ID,t,'yes'))]
```

Comment: You're trying to evaluate SQL syntax with Pandas `eval`.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, what's your suggestion? I added something on my original question.

Comment: The second version is normal Python syntax, so of course it works. Use `df.sort()` to sort your dataframe.

Comment: Hi @Barmar, But that's after the selection, right? Can we do 'order' before the new dataframe is formed to save time? My HistoryThreshold can be 360, and there maybe thousands of rows to select from, I wqs hoping to stop selection as long as I have 361 (on or before the HOUR).

Comment: I don't know, I'm not really proficient with pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use the eval function to do that. You can use masks in python. Here is what it looks like :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [x for x in range(10)], 
                   'Date' : [datetime.strptime('Jun {} 2019'.format(x), '%b %d %Y') 
                             for x in range(1, 11)]})

t = datetime.strptime('Jun 09 2019', '%b %d %Y')
threshold = 5

df[df.Date < t][0:threshold]

   ID       Date
0   0 2019-06-01
1   1 2019-06-02
2   2 2019-06-03
3   3 2019-06-04
4   4 2019-06-05
```

---

If you want to be sure the selected rows are the ones the closest to your limit date you could sort your df in an descending way :

```
df.sort_values('Date', ascending=False, inplace = True)
df[df.Date < t][0:threshold]

   ID       Date
7   7 2019-06-08
6   6 2019-06-07
5   5 2019-06-06
4   4 2019-06-05
3   3 2019-06-04
```

Comment: Thanks, @vlemaistre.

Comment: Glad to help. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.